# savehistory command doesn't work in R 4.02

Tags: r

I tried using the command `savehistory()` in R version 4.02 on MacOS. It did gave an error:

```r
savehistory()
```

> Error in .External2(C_savehistory, file): 'savehistory' is not currently implemented

`savehistory` is a standard R command that is cited in all R manuals.

Anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Similarly, from [`?savehistory`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/savehistory.html): *"R.app, the console on macOS, has a separate and largely incompatible history mechanism, which by default uses a file ‘.Rapp.history’ and saves up to 250 entries. These functions are not currently implemented there."*

Answer (score 1):

Look at [R for Mac OS X FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#History). Mac OS has never supported `savehistory`. If you are using the R Console, the "History" icon on the top bar pops out a drawer on the left side of the window displaying your history. Note the buttons at the bottom:

[image: History]

Comment: Thanks to both responders. You answered my question.